# Angular 8 universal server side rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am following this tutorial https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/ but I couldn't execute the first command

```
 ng generate universal --client-project -the name of your client project-
```

the error is

```
Target name already exists.
```

any suggestions or if anyone has a better solution to implement angular universal on an existing angular project?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of error? I guess that you aren't executing the command properly.

Comment: C:\projects\project-name>ng g universal --client-project project-name
Target name already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run your command like this with `=` sign:

```
ng generate universal --client-project=YourApplicationName
```

Comment: if i use the name of the application the error is: "Target name already exists" and if use Myapp1 the error is :Universal requires a project type of "application".

Comment: thank you it worked, and i had another problem, that the project name in angular.json and package.json are not the same.thanks so much

Comment: @KamesGuen just rename your name of application in `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I already had server object in angular.json. I mean in projects.[project name]. architect.server
Just remove it, if it unnecessary for you, and command will work

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as shown above **StepUp**

> ng generate universal --client-project=`application-name`

where `<application_name>` is the name you can find in your package.json ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdklV.jpg))

Here, I'll run

> ng generate universal --client-project=client